# Creating form fields from user input

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I found a code that creates some  form fields based on a number chose by the user.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
         function addFields(){
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = "Member["+i+"]";
                container.appendChild(input);
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
</script>


<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of Members: <br />
<input type="button" id="enterdetails" value = "Enter Details"onclick="addFields()">
<div id="container"/>
</div>
```

It works fine. But I want to create  elements with  names/values imported from a database. In php I do like this:

```
<SELECT name='smth'>
<OPTION value=""></OPTION>
<?php

$qry = $dbh->query("select * FROM table");

while ($a = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$smth = $a['smth'];
echo "<OPTION value='$smth'>".$smth."</OPTION>";
}
?> 
</SELECT>
```

Need help on how to do it in javascript.

Comment: "Need help on how to do it in javascript." What does that mean? You want to retrieve database values using javascript? If so, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get database fields with javascript. You must use php or something like this.

Maybe this can help you. [Here is the link](http://grafanimasyon.blogspot.com.tr/2015/02/veritabanndan-php-form-olusturucu.html). choose your database and table, and select your field names, and choose field's type of form (text area, text, radio button groups, etc) and push create. You will have a bootstrap designed form and php insert code writed with medoo (medoo.in).

you can use this. create your database first and make form automaticly. Copy code and paste to your pages.

Also i offer you to use meddo to connect and use sql with it. There is a sample in that link form.min.php, includes your database and user and pass information.